# how much resources does firebase on()/addValueEventListener takes?

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I see that Firebase website has a lot of documentation to help us optimize the usage of resources, however, I have not found a detailed example of the resources used.
This could be useful to me to understand how to build my applications and to better choose the strategy in terms of performance and cost.

TAKING ANDROID AS EXAMPLE

I understand that when i do a:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

all the reference is "queried" to the database so that is a single query but takes down all the object.

if i do:

```
query.addValueEventListener(...);
```

the connection is kept open, but will it keep making connections on time intervals? 
Or maybe is considered like a single connection in terms of billing?
And after a change on the database, will it query all the object down again?

In general how much is heavier and expensive to make a single request vs using the realtime-db feature of listening to a reference?

Maybe there is a section in the docs that explain this but I didn't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

> all the reference queried" to the database so that is a single
>   query but takes down all the object.

It will listen once to the objects within inside the child you are querying, not all of the objects inside the database.

```
query.addValueEventListener(...);
```

> the connection is kept open, but will it keep making connections on
>   time intervals?

It has no intervals, instead it listens whenever a change is made into your database, lets say you change certain value from your database and that will trigger your `addValueEventListener`. This will only consume resources when some value changes into your database, so the usage will be a variant with your database usage, instead , `addListenerForSingleValue` will fire just once to query your data and we can assure that it will consume less network resources than a listener that is always listen to some changes to bring into your app

Check this usefull link : https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ValueEventListener.html

Comment: Thanks Gaston, so this means "addListenerForSingleValue" download the child once, and the data usage of "addValueEventListener" takes place the first time it is called AND when the child is changed on the database. Being (first case) < (second case) in term of resources, a comparison does not have so mutch sense because it depends on the frequence of changes. This is right?